# CodeIgniter Active Records is not auto escaping a single quote while inserting the data

Tags: codeigniter, escaping

I'm developing an ecommerce site in CodeIgniter 3.1.11 and Active Records does not escape the single quote automatically. But in the documentation it is mentioned that Active records will automatically escapes the input.

```
$ar = array(
   'name'=>"Jon'", //see the extra single quote here after the name Jon
);
$this->db->insert('test',$ar);
```

this code will add single quote in database and if i fetch this data and display this in HTML then any one can execute inline js there Eg. `Jon' onmouseover='alert(1)` this input will execute inline js on the page.
`<input type='text' name='username' value='Jon' onmouseover='alert(1)'`
See here the onmouseover is added as the extra attribute.

```
$ar = array(
   'name'=>$this->db->escape_str("Jon'"), //see the extra single quote here after the name Jon
);
$this->db->insert('test',$ar);
```

i have tried the **escape_str** function manually but this is adding backward slash before the single quote `Jon\'`so inline js will not execute but its an ecommerce site it might be possible that there may be genuine single quotes are also there eg. **Men's Clothes , Women's Clothes** but if i use **escape_str** then it will be displayed as `Mens\'s Clothes ,Women\'s Clothes` what to do in this situation? Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CI's function [escape_str()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=escape#CI_DB_driver::escape_str) to manually escape strings and when getting the data back the php function [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
echo html_entity_decode('joe\', Mens\'s Clothes, Women\'s Clothes');
```

which outputs

```
joe', Mens's Clothes, Women's Clothes
```

or better change your input field to:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" onmouseover="alert(1)">
```

then the automatic escaping from CI insert() will serve you, as inserting `joe'` into value results in

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="joe'" onmouseover="alert(1)">
```

**edit:** hence you commented there are many files to change, you can also use this approach with [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

this php function transforms a single quote into `&#039;` and hence doesn't interfere with other single quotes in your code. The output by the browser is `'`

```
$ar = array(
   'name'=>htmlentities("Jon'", ENT_QUOTES)
);
$this->db->insert('test',$ar);
```

note the use of the flag `ENT_QUOTES`:  *which will convert both double and single quotes.*

now in your html you'll get this code when getting the value from the database:

```html
<input type='text' name='username' value='Jon&#039;' onmouseover='alert(1)'>
```

which is not interfering anymore with your other single quotes (just run the code snippet)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I'm facing this problem in so many different pages. So changing this on each and every page will be time consuming. Is there any function in CodeIgniter active records that auto escapes the input or output while fetching or inserting the data?

Comment: @SagarGor I've updated my answer, that should suit you now...

Comment: Okay I think this is the thing that I want. Thank you for your valuable time and answer.

Comment: But I'm little bit confused in one thing if you can help me in that will be also helpful to me. Why CodeIgniter 3.1.11 is not auto escaping the quotes even after it is mentioned in the documentation here. [Inserting Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

Comment: with autoescape, you'll get `joe'`back from the database, which will mess up your markup (since as per your comment you are not able to change the single quotes to doublequotes). Hence the solution with htmlentities().